# Any way to find the jquery object index when binding event for each jquery object in an array?

Tags: jquery

```
$("input").on("click", function(){
  //how do i find the the input index here?
});
```

instead of doing the following, I am trying to find a smarter way.
any good idea?

```
$("input").eq(0).on("click", function(){
  //do something for eq(0)  
});

$("input").eq(1).on("click", function(){
  //do something for eq(1)  
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function. There are two ways of calling this.

### If all the elements are siblings

If all the elements are siblings of the same parent element and there are no other elements within that parent, you can use `$(this).index()`.

When `index` is called without any parameters, it gets the element's position among its siblings. So the first child of the parent will be `0`, the second `1`, etc.

### If the elements aren't all siblings

If the document structure is more complicated, then you'll have to search among a particular set. This means taking a selection of all the elements that you want to search among, and then passing the element you want to search for as the first parameter. It's exactly as if you were doing an `indexOf` search on an array.

```
var inputs = $("input").on("click", function(){
    console.log(inputs.index(this));
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the clicked element to the jQuery's `index` method:

```
var $input = $("input");
$input.on("click", function() {
   var i = $input.index(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this`

```
$("input").on("click", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
});
```

This will find the index of the clicked input in relation to that of its sibling inputs. Example:

```
<div>
    <input type='text'/> //index 0
    <input type='text'/> //index 1
</div>
<div>
    <input type='text'/> //index 0
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes that all `input` elements are siblings.

Comment: @FelixKling -- Yes, I'm adding it to the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#sdf">abc</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#wer">def</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#xcv">ghi</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#poi">jkl</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="count"></div>
```

This will return the index of each a element using the more up to date .on() method

```
$("#list li a").on('click', function () {
    var index = $("#list li a").index(this) + 1;
    $("#count").html(index);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access the DOM element that is in the current iteration of the selector, you will use `$(this)`. If you want to find the *actual index of the DOM element in relation to the matched elements*, which will be an *integer*, then you will use `.index()`.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzq4/) to demonstrate this.

```
$('.indexme').bind('click',function(){

    //$(this) is a jquery object of the currently matched DOM element
    //.index() will return the integer value of the actual index

    $(this).append($(this).index());

});
```

Comment: `$(this)` will return a jQuery object containing `this`, not the index.